# Inconsistent spacing between outward frame ticks and tick labels in Mathematica 13

Tags: plotting, ticks

I want to use FrameTicks with the ticks pointing outward in the negative direction. Take these example functions for FrameTicks and a plot:

```
myTicks[l_] := {{0, 0, {0, l}}, {1, 1, {0, l}}, {2, 2, {0, l}}};
length = 0.04;

myPlot[ticks_, aspect_] := Plot[
    x, {x, 0, 2}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
    FrameTicks -> {ticks, ticks}, AspectRatio -> aspect
];
```

With an aspect ratio of 1, the plot looks normal.

```
aspectRatio = 1;
myPlot[myTicks[length], aspectRatio]
```

[image]

With an aspect ratio of 0.2, the ticks run into the tick labels:

```
aspectRatio = 0.2;
myPlot[myTicks[length], aspectRatio]
```

[image]

With an aspect ratio of 3, the ticks are shortened, especially for the horizontal axis:

```
aspectRatio = 3;
myPlot[myTicks[length], aspectRatio]
```

[image]

The original length can be recovered by multiplying the tick length by the aspect ratio, but now there is too much space between ticks and tick labels for the horizontal axis:

```
aspectRatio = 3;
myPlot[myTicks[length*aspectRatio], aspectRatio]
```

[image]

I'm using version 13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86. In version 12.x and before, I could work around this issue by using a negative number as the positive tick length and setting the negative tick length to 0. However, that no longer works now. Does anyone know a workaround for this issue? Thanks.

Comment: It's a huge pain, and you'd have to tune it on a case by case basis, but you could use something like: `myTicks[l_] := {{0, 
    RawBoxes[AdjustmentBox[0, BoxBaselineShift -> 2.5]], {0, l}}, {1, 
    1, {0, l}}, {2, 2, {0, l}}};` as a workaround. Obviously, I only applied the workaround to the first tick and I optimized it for the `0.2` ratio case.

Comment: Thanks for that! It could work for aspect ratios less than 1 but unfortunately it can't help with those greater than 1. I've reported this to Wolfram Support and they don't know of a workaround either, but apparently they've made their technical staff aware of the issue.